# getting directory of page using php

Tags: php

what i am trying to do is to get directory of my page like this

```
Home / Clothes / Something
```

i have tried this but i didn't understand a lot in this but it doesn't work as i want it

```
<?php

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

chdir('cvs');

// current directory
echo getcwd() . "\n";

?>
```

here's example what i need to do

my page is example.com/clothes/something.php

and on that page "something.php" i want to echo out something like this

```
<a href="example.com">Home</a> / <a href="example.com/clothes/">clothes</a> / <a href="example.com/clothes/something.php">Something</a>
```

i forget what this was called but hope you understand

```
<?php 
    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"/\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i])."</a> » ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$subPath = '';
$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($path);

foreach ($path as $segment) {
  $subPath.= $segment.'/';
  echo "<A HREF=\"http://www.php.loc/$subPath\">$segment</A> / ";      
}
```

You may need to tweak it a bit, but that's the basic idea.

[EDIT]

Or maybe something like this:

```
$Pages = [
  '/clothes' => 'Clothes',
  '/clothes/something.php' => 'Something'
];

$subPath = '';
$BreadCrumbs = [];
$path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($path);

foreach ($path as $segment) {
  $subPath.= '/'.$segment;
  $BreadCrumbs[] = "<A HREF=\"http://www.php.loc$subPath\">$Pages[$subPath]</A>";
}

echo implode(' &gt; ', $BreadCrumbs);
```

If your version of PHP is before [5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), then you'll need a different syntax for the arrays:

```
$Pages = array(
  '/clothes' => 'Clothes',
  '/clothes/something.php' => 'Something'
);

$BreadCrumbs = array();
```

[EDIT]

OK, one last go:

```
<?php
    $Pages = array(
      'clothes' => 'Clothes',
      'something' => 'Something'
    );

    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"/\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Comment: that's great dear but how do i change name of the page that i get to something i want ? and how do i put > instead of /

Comment: Well, you can just change / to > in the output. I'm not sure what you mean by changing the name of the page to something you want.

Comment: ok i changed / to > but what i mean by name is right now using the code i get folder name and page name like this folder/name.php i get on out put like this "folder > name >" also there should not be > at the end

Comment: OK, I *think* I understand what you're saying, though not sure. Check out my edit, and see if that does it for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your hard work dear but there is few other things i don't know how to fix them

Comment: first of all i am getting error on  $Pages = [ and on $BreadCrumbs = []; if you check on dreamweaver

Comment: and secondly, i want to add a Home before folder name and how do i change this http://www.php.loc to my domain name home page? i tried http://www.domain.com it doesn't work

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? As for changing the domain, just change it to whatever domain you're working on. What are you hoping to do with this? Is it part of a larger project? These last questions you're asking are very basic; I do not wish to be rude, but if you cannot figure them out, this may be something more than you can handle.

Comment: well bro, i didn't get on your code but i have another code that works much easier for me but i am not able to post it here for few mins if you can edit it for me as this one. just like i said in your code i want to put names that i want

Comment: i have just add a second code on my question please check it. that works very much easier for me

Comment: OK, cool, if you got something that works for you, that's great. Good luck!

Comment: bro, i just need your help to edit my code that works for me . what is wrong ?

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to tell you. From what I can see, the second code you posted does what you're looking for. No? If I run it on my server, at url `http://localhost/php/lib/sublib/test.php` I get `Home » php » lib » sublib » test`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: dear my friend. i really appreciate all your hard work. but what i am saying here is when i told you to make some how i can change the names to what i want and you did it. you have add this to your code $Pages = [
  '/clothes' => 'Clothes',
  '/clothes/something.php' => 'Something'
]; i want same way i do on second code as you said second code worked yes it worked but you see it shows on output folder name and file name. i should be able to name it instead of getting folder name and file name on output. i am really sorry brother

Comment: OK, well all you need is an associative array like the `$Pages` array like the one in the third code sample of my answer, then use the elements of your `$parts` array as an index to this array, on lines 17 and 24 of your code. Give it a try.

Comment: i don't understand a lot on making codes bro i can only edit some etc. can you please make that for me ?

Comment: OK, there you have it. Good luck with it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 33 in C:\xampp\htdocs\clothes\something.php on line 41

Comment: this line is 41 echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);

Comment: Well, you have to modify the `$Page` array so that its indices are whatever ends up in your `$parts` array. The `$Pages` array maps the parts of your file path to whatever you want the pages called. I don't know what else I can tell you.

Comment: alright , thanks for all you did. looks like you're not in a good mod. but sorry for everything. thanks again

Comment: it worked very well now. and figured that i had a little mistake